# Async hbase 'non-blocking' calls lock thread for ~70ms, why?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, hbase, blocking

I'm using this tool for talking to hbase:

```
org.hbase:asynchbase:1.7.0
```

**Why does the following code take ~70 ms?**

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
Deferred<ArrayList<KeyValue>> meta = hbaseClient.get(new GetRequest(propsCtx.hbaseTable, rowIdMeta(tsnfdr.id)));
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
log.info("supposed 'non-blocking' async hbase call took {} millis", end - start);
```

(The call to 'propsCtx.hbaseTable' and 'rowIdMeta(tsnfdr.id)' is not the problem).

The docs are very limited, but from the signature of the method, observations in visualvm on usage of netty threads under the hood, and a quick look at the source code tells me that I'm supposed to be using an async api.

Comment: Try made this call in the loop, possible it hides some initial initialization.

Comment: @AlexanderKuznetsov: Thanks for the hint, I'll do more sampling, perhaps the time will go down.